# Run docker container via a setuid binary

Tags: docker, setuid

I am trying to set up a container on my (debian stretch) server, and to lock it down as much as possible.

The container `my-container` only needs to be started, it then does some processing and returns (the whole thing takes about one second).

I can easily do it as root with `docker start -a my-container`.

My problem is that this processing needs to be triggered with a php script. Instead of giving www-data the right to start docker containers, I created a dedicated user, with a small setuid binary that executes the docker command.

Now, executing the setuid binary from another user doesn't work and returns:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/my-container/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

While executing the binary from the special user account works.

I use `4510` permissions:

```
-r-s--x--- 1 docker-proxy-launcher another-user 8448 sept. 23 23:43 /home/docker-proxy-launcher/docker-prestage
```

The binary is a very simple program, derived from the `execve` man page:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *newenviron[] = { NULL };
char * newargv[] = {NULL, "start", "-a", "my-container", NULL};
char * exec="/usr/bin/docker";

newargv[0] = exec;

execve(exec, newargv, newenviron);
perror("execve"); /* execve() only returns on error */
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I really don't get what is preventing me from launching the docker process with this setuid binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured this out myself. The `setuid` bit just changes the user id, not the group id of the process. As a result, the executable has the rights of the new user, but not the ones from the groups it belongs to.

As a workaround, I changed the binary to be owned by `root:docker` (as belonging to the docker group gives the permission to write on the docker socket):

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 sept. 23 23:09 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I also changed the permissions to be `2111` (`setgid`, executable by anyone as it is not a security issue on my system; if it was, I think I could have used ACLs):

```
---x--s--x 1 root docker 8448 sept. 24 10:58 /home/docker-proxy-launcher/docker-prestage
```

It now all works properly.

Comment: In two hours (SO limit, I can't accept it less than 48 hours after the question was asked) ;)

Comment: Okie, I didn't knew about that till now :-)